# Set the backcolor of a WinAPI toolbar with Visual Styles?

Tags: c++, c, winapi

Is there a way to set the background color. I thought of making a dummy window and then using TBSTATE_TRANSPARENT, but I thought there might be a cleaner solution?

Thanks

None of these solutions work for a toolbar using visual styles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [TB_SETCOLORSCHEME](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb787421(v=VS.85).aspx).

Comment: When visual styles are enabled, this message has no effect.

Comment: Also this sets button color not back color

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is redraw the toolbar entirely by handling WM_PAINT

Read this article: http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/controls/toolbar/flattoolbar/article.php/c2535/

Answer (score 0):

Could you subclass the toolbar window and either handle the WM_ERASEBKGND message or handle the WM_CTLCOLORDLG message and return your desired background brush?

You might also be able to do something with WM_CTLCOLORBTN - this doesn't require that you subclass the window since it's handed to the parent window.

Answer (score 0):

You can call `SetClassLong()` with `GCL_HBRBACKGROUND` and pass a brush you created with `CreateSolidBrush()`.
You can also pass in a pattern brush if you want the background to be an image.